# Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestoreDocument: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using angular 11 with firebase for authentication and firestore for collection of data and I am getting `Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestoreDocument: (?, ?)` error. How do I fix this null injector error? I tried to remove provider and it throws error `NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestoreDocument!`
Here is my code of app module.
app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {AuthService} from './shared/services/auth.service';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './pages/profile/profile.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';


import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AngularFirestoreDocument],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

errror:
[image: error when AngularFirestoreDocument is added to provider]

[image: error when AngularFirestoreDocument is reomved from provider]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue has been hit by multiple people in the past, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513028/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-angularfirestores-object-object) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1206) for reference.

With that being said, I'm not entirely sure you're running into the same issue, because your `app.module.ts` looks different - you haven't included `AngularFirestore` in your imports.

According to the [AngularFire docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md), you need to import `AngularFirestore`, and `AngularFirestoreDocument` when using `AngularFirestoreDocument`. I'm especially thinking this could be your issue because of the second error you have there, where there's no provider for `AngularFirestoreDocument`.

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Additionally, some of the other answers on the linked SO post said that you should remove `AngularFirestore` as a provider, but I'm not sure that would work in your instance with you not having it as a provider already with `AngularFirestoreDocument` instead, and those answers were before AngularFire version 6, which I'm assuming you're using already since you're on Angular 11.

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this error ? I am having same error and couldn't found any solution to github thread.

Comment: Are you getting the same error after trying the methods I suggested? What happens when you import both `AngularFirestore` and `AngularFirestoreDocument`?

Comment: If i import both of those the error remain same.